# Can one $_POST['name'] insert different data into two columns?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a form where I have a choice of human avatars. Avatar 1 has blonde hair and blue eyes, Avatar 2 has brown hair and brown eyes.

I have this form input for the avatars

```
<input type="radio" name="avatarblondeblue" value="blondeblue">
<input type="radio" name="avatarbrownbrown" value="brownbrown">
```

In my MySQL table, I have one column called "hair_color" and one column called "eye_color".

Is it possible to use just one input to submit, for example, "blonde" to column hair_color and also "blue" to column eye_color?

**EDIT:** Solution was to set names the same and create an if-then statement like this:

```
if ($_POST['avatar'] == 'blondeblue') {
    $hair_color = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, 'blonde');
    $eye_color = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, 'blue');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a solution for your issue to choose avatars. You have to the same name to both input radio and put your data in the value attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $data=explode("b",$_POST['avatar']);
    echo "hair_color - b".$data[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "eye_color - b".$data[1];
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="radio" name="avatar" value="blondeblue"> Avatar Blonde Blue 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="avatar" value="brownbrown"> Avatar Brown Brown
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```